# How to enable the edit feature of "Photos" in my app? [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

**Issue:**

Even if this is set to true:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

It **only shows** the crop feature, which works for iPhone-sized devices **but not for iPad sized devices** (cropping won't work properly, it returns the wrong part of the picture).

[image]
[image]

How could I enable the edit functionality of the "Photos", so that the user may instead use this crop feature?

[image]

Did finish method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    isImageChanged = true

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        //Code for iPad problem
        pictureBox.image = image
    }else{
        pictureBox.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        pictureBox.image = image
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Calling ImagePickerController

```
let alertAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){(UIAlertAction)-> Void in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            }
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your `didFinishPicking` method.

Comment: Edited answer, @NiravD

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163656/uiimagepickercontroller-that-allowsediting-incorrectly-crops-the-image-leaving-a ?

Comment: It's unanswered and sadly a still recurring bug from the apple side. Since there's no solution as of now, I'm asking how to enable the features found in "Photos" to somehow bypass this problem, if possible and there's a way to use it.

Comment: No, you can't make the editing powers of the Photos app appear in your app by magic. You can certainly add editing powers _of your own_ in your app. Write your own cropping interface, for example. Or you could put the image into the user's photo library and let the user edit it _in the Photos app_.

Comment: I hope apple does something to fix that cropping bug on iPads tho @.@ anyways, please write it down as the answer so that I could mark it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and there is a simple solution. When using the imagePickerController on iPad's you have to present it as a popover in order for editing to work properly. [Source](http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-picker-controller-tutorial-ios/)

Below are some images to illustrate that editing works.

[image][image]

Next, we have the issue of the popOver on an iPhone. The popover cannot display on an iPhone so it will just display the normal picker which takes up the whole screen. Note you might also want to check if you have access to the photo library or camera too. (Code for that is in the link provided above.)

```
@IBAction func selectImagePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // check if we can access the library first? If no we need to ask again
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary // can be camera or library

        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView =  view

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let xLocation = (screenSize.width / 100) * 15
        let yLocation = (screenSize.height / 2)
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: xLocation, y: yLocation, width: 0, height: 0)

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            // Use editedImage Here
            self.imageView.image = editedImage
            nextButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            // Use originalImage Here
            self.imageView.image = originalImage
            nextButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            if let vc = UIApplication.topViewController() {
                Helper.showAlertMessage(vc: vc, title: "Image Error", message: "An error occured during image selection")
            }
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```